Having trouble with recursion. Keeps getting incorrect outputs
In the language of an alien race, all words take the form of Blurbs. A Blurb
is a Whoozit followed by one or more Whatzits. A Whoozit is the character
'x' followed by zero or more 'y's. A Whatzit is a 'q' followed by either a
'z' or a 'd', followed by a Whoozit.
Design and implement a recursive program to determine whether a string is a
valid Blurb. The user should be able to enter a string, and the program
should print whether or not that string is a Blurb (either "true" or "false").
I have been hammering away at this problem and have come to this bit of code as the closest I can get to a answer:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Blurb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string to find out whether it is a blurb:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean isValid = isValidBlurb(input);
        System.out.println(isValid);
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static boolean isValidBlurb(String str) {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            return false; // Empty string is not a valid Blurb
        }

        // Check if the string starts with 'x', which is always a Whoozit
        if (str.charAt(0) == 'x') {
            return isValidWhoozit(str.substring(1)); // Check the rest of the Blurb
        }

        return false; // Invalid start of a Blurb
    }

    private static boolean isValidWhoozit(String str) {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            return true; // Empty Whoozit is valid in a Blurb
        }

        // Check if the string starts with 'y' or 'qz' or 'qd' and recursively call isValidWhoozit
        if (isValidWhatzit(str)) {
            return isValidWhoozit(str.substring(3)); // Continue checking the rest of the Whoozit
        } else if (str.charAt(0) == 'y') {
            return isValidWhoozit(str.substring(1)); // Continue checking the rest of the Whoozit
        }

        return false; // Invalid Whoozit
    }

    private static boolean isValidWhatzit(String str) {
        if (str.length() >= 3) {
            String prefix = str.substring(0, 3);
            return prefix.equals("qz") || prefix.equals("qd");
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Given the following was entered from the keyboard:
xyyyy
you displayed:
Enter a string to find out whether it is a blurb:true
instead of:
Enter a string to find out whether it is a blurb:false
It keeps reading this "xyyy" as true but I'm unsure as to what I am doing wrong.

You should ideally know what's wrong before posting, and you do that by debugging your code. Go through your code line by line. You have an idea of what is supposed to be happening at each step. Compare what is actually happening with that expectation. If you systematically debug your code whenever you run into a problem, you will solve 95+% of your problems without ever having to ask for help. Once you identify the problem, if you then don't know how to fix it, that's the time to ask.

As @MarsAtomic said, run your program under the debugger, with some simple inputs and see exactly where it gets them wrong.

But without a debugger it is clear that prefix.equals("qz") || prefix.equals("qd") can never be true, comparing a string length 3 with a string length 2...

And the other error,  I believe, is logic, not programming: I don't think an empty Whoozit is valid...

Apologies if this is vague or uninformative. I have been hammering this one problem for nearly a week now with no sleep so my brain is kinda mushed.

Also, I cannot put the code into a debugger as the place I am putting the code itself is on a website called MPL.

Then install an IDE (e.g. the free edition of IntelliJ IDEA) and develop the code locally first.

@Turo When isValidWhoozit is called, we have already parsed the leading 'x', so I think that's okay...

As I see it, you need to iterate the letters in the input while keeping track of what the next letter should be. This implies an iterative solution. An iterative solution can usually be translated to a recursive solution. Hence, in order to solve the problem, I began by implementing an iterative solution and then translated it to a recursive solution.
Here is a kind of syntax diagram – using regular expression metacharacters – that describes the structure of a blurb:
blurb : whoozit , whatzit+
whoozit : x , y*
whatzit : q , (z|d) , whoozit


+ means "one or more"
* means "zero or more"
| means either one

So a blurb is a whoozit followed by one or more whatzits.
The logic is therefore...

a blurb must begin with the lowercase letter x
the next letter must be either y or q
if it's a q then the next letter must be either d or z
the letter following a d or a z must be x

The last three steps basically repeat themselves. In other words, after an x must come either y or q and so on.
Together with the above, you also need to keep track of whether you have a whoozit or a whatzit.
Here is the iterative solution:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlurbIterative {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string to find out whether it is a blurb:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean hasWhoozit = false;
        boolean hasWhatzit = false;
        boolean isValid = true;
        int length = input.length();
        int index = 0;
        while (index < length  &&  isValid) {
            if (index == 0) {
                isValid = input.charAt(index) == 'x';
            }
            else {
                if (!hasWhoozit) {
                    isValid = input.charAt(index) == 'y';
                    if (!isValid) {
                        isValid = input.charAt(index) == 'q';
                        if (isValid) {
                            hasWhoozit = true;
                            index++;
                            if (index >= length) {
                                isValid = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                isValid = input.charAt(index) == 'd'  ||  input.charAt(index) == 'z';
                                if (isValid) {
                                    hasWhatzit = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (hasWhatzit) {
                        isValid = input.charAt(index) == 'x';
                        hasWhatzit = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = input.charAt(index) == 'y';
                        if (!isValid) {
                            isValid = input.charAt(index) == 'q';
                            if (isValid) {
                                index++;
                                if (index >= length) {
                                    isValid = false;
                                }
                                else {
                                    isValid = input.charAt(index) == 'd'  ||  input.charAt(index) == 'z';
                                    if (isValid) {
                                        hasWhatzit = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
        isValid = index == length  &&  hasWhoozit  &&  !hasWhatzit;
        System.out.println(isValid);
        scanner.close();
    }
}

Here is the recursive solution:
(I suggest that you compare the iterative and recursive solutions to see how they differ. Basically, the recursive method calls itself with an incremented index parameter. This is essentially how to convert an iterative solution to a recursive one.)
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlurbRecursive {

    private static boolean isValidBlurb(String str,
                                        int index,
                                        boolean isValid,
                                        boolean hasWhoozit,
                                        boolean hasWhatzit) {
        if (isValid) {
            int length = str.length();
            if (index < length) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    isValid = str.charAt(index) == 'x';
                }
                else {
                    if (!hasWhoozit) {
                        isValid = str.charAt(index) == 'y';
                        if (!isValid) {
                            isValid = str.charAt(index) == 'q';
                            if (isValid) {
                                hasWhoozit = true;
                                index++;
                                if (index >= length) {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                isValid = str.charAt(index) == 'd'  ||  str.charAt(index) == 'z';
                                if (isValid) {
                                    hasWhatzit = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (hasWhatzit) {
                            isValid = str.charAt(index) == 'x';
                            hasWhatzit = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            isValid = str.charAt(index) == 'y';
                            if (!isValid) {
                                isValid = str.charAt(index) == 'q';
                                if (isValid) {
                                    index++;
                                    if (index >= length) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                    isValid = str.charAt(index) == 'd'  ||  str.charAt(index) == 'z';
                                    if (isValid) {
                                        hasWhatzit = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return isValidBlurb(str, index + 1, isValid, hasWhoozit, hasWhatzit);
            }
            return isValid  &&  hasWhoozit  &&  !hasWhatzit;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string to find out whether it is a blurb:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean isValid = isValidBlurb(input, 0, true, false, false);
        System.out.println(isValid);
        scanner.close();
    }
}

Note that the code in your question is neither iterative nor recursive. Here is a solution in the vein of the code in your question, i.e. neither iterative nor recursive. By the way, according to the definition of a blurb, an empty string is not a valid blurb – contrary to what is stated in the code in your question.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Blurb {
    private static int  index;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a string to find out whether it is a blurb:");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean isValid = isValidBlurb(input);
        System.out.println(isValid);
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static boolean isValidBlurb(String str) {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            return false; // Empty string is not a valid Blurb
        }

        if (isValidWhoozit(str)) {
            int length = str.length();
            if (index + 3 <= length) {
                while (index < length  &&  isValidWhatzit(str.substring(index))) {
                    // Empty loop body.
                }
                return index == length;
            }
        }
        return false; // Invalid start of a Blurb
    }

    private static boolean isValidWhoozit(String str) {
        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (str.charAt(0) == 'x') {
            index++;
            int len = str.length();
            for (int i = 1; i < len  &&  str.charAt(i) == 'y'; i++) {
                index++;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false; // Invalid Whoozit
    }

    private static boolean isValidWhatzit(String str) {
        if (str.length() >= 3) {
            String prefix = str.substring(0, 2);
            if (prefix.equals("qz") || prefix.equals("qd")) {
                index += 2;
                return isValidWhoozit(str.substring(2));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

